# Execute matlab on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, matlab, aws-lambda

We have ~6TB of training data on aws EFS storage and need to process this dataset with Matlab. In order to avoid downloading the data into local servers and upload them back, we’d need to run matlab within aws. Is there any way to achieve this? Is there MatLab execution capability within the aws?

Comment: Absolutely! I've run MATLAB on EC2 instances without any issue, and you can definitely mount EFS storage on EC2 instances. Some reading: (1) Getting started with EC2: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/getting-started/ (2) Mounting EFS on EC2: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Mathworks not only provides official instructions for that

- https://github.com/mathworks-ref-arch/matlab-on-aws

but also [CloudFormation templates](https://github.com/mathworks-ref-arch/matlab-on-aws/tree/master/releases/R2020a) which will create your Matlab environment for you with an instance, security groups and remote login capabilities. When setting this up, you can specify an **instance role** to enable access to other AWS services, such as EFS.

When you launch their template you will have to provide the following info:

[image]

And when it launches (Ubuntu 18.04) you can use RDP for remote desktop:

[image]